# sort -u works wrong in some cases

Tags: unix

Input file contains two lines:

```
추가
나인
```

Running `uniq` and `sort -u` commands:

```
$ uniq -c input_file 
    2 추가
$ sort -u input_file
    추가
```

For some reasons these two strings are "equal" when they are adjacent. (tested on debian and ubuntu)
On Mac it works fine:

```
$ sort -u input_file
    나인
    추가
```

Comment: different $KCODE settings? (or some other similar variable?) LC_COLLATE or LC_ALL maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`uniq` works only on sorted data. Is this what you are asking for? See man pages.

Answer (score 0):

Changing locale configuration helped:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Thanks  Shawn!